# Why don't games load assets while showing main menu?

Tags: performance, loading

Most single player computer games have rather frustrating pattern of loading:

1. start game
2. Game shows you some logo videos
3. Game indicates it is loading (general assets are loading, that are always used)
4. Main menu shows
5. Select and load game
6. More loading
7. You can play now

Loading of general assets could be in theory done while already showing main menu, unless the main menu contains some elaborate graphics itself.

There must be some obstruction, since I am not aware of many modern games that show the menu immediately. What prevents creators to load assets asynchronously while player is selecting things in main menu?

Or other way to phrase the question: If I wanted to have my game show menuy while still loading assets, what problems do I need to solve?

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you're after, here, you answer both questions yourself: _"Now the game doesn't know which game you will want to load usually"_, and _"make a very precise guess"_.

Comment: I removed that part since it seems to be confusing. I was asking why the assets that are loaded before main menu (most games do that) are not loaded while the menu is shown and then possibly continue loading while also loading savegame.

Comment: We can't tell you why "games" do thing A or B universally — you'd need to ask each game's creator individually to find that out. We can help you solve problems in *your* game's implementation though. How have you tried implementing this feature so far? What problems did you encounter? Maybe you won't have a problem with it at all!

Comment: The game has already told you to get ready to wait by showing you some logo videos, how beneficial is it really to get the player into the main menu right after the logos, at the cost of having the menu kind of lag due to the loading going on in the background?